# Customizing the insert widget type 'Catalog Products List' template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I'm adding the widget on a page by going 
->Insert Widget ->Widget type-> Catalog Products List
After adding the widget, I can see the template path as 'template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml"'. I'm trying to update this template but working on a wrong file I guess. What is the full path for the template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full path to your template file will be :

`<Vendor>/<YourTheme>/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`